# Select2 Dropdown autoselect if only 1 option available

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a select2 dropdown box using remote datasource.

What I would like to do is if/when there is only one option returned by the search, auto select it. ie, the user doesn;t have to click on the option to make the selection.

```
$("#searchInfo_Entity_Key").select2({
ajax: {
    url: "/Adjustment/GetEntity",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
        return {
            term: params.term, // search term      
        };
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
        return {
            results: data
        };
    },
    results: function (data) {
        return { results: data };
    },
},
initSelection: function (element, callback) {
    var data = [];
    callback(data);
},
minimumInputLength: 2,
allowClear: true,
placeholder: "Select an entity"
```

});

Comment: _Are you sure_ you want this? If the user mistypes and only gets one result, and it automatically selects it, that's terrible UX.

Comment: Not my call :( They pick it, I stick it. Told them the exact same thing but got over ruled.

Comment: unfortunately not. It got shelved as a "nice to have" and never revisited.

Answer (score 2):

This is a custom matcher, that wraps around the default matcher and counts how many matches there are. If there is only one match, then it will select that match, change it, and close the dropdown box.

(Not tested with remote data.)

```js
$(function() {
  
  var matchCount = 0; // Track how many matches there are
  var matched; // Track the ID of the last match
  
  $('select').select2({
    placeholder: 'Product Search',
    allowClear: true,
    matcher: function(params, data) {
      // Wrap the default matcher that we have just overridden.
      var match = $.fn.select2.defaults.defaults.matcher(params, data);
            
      // If this is the first option that we are testing against,
      // reset the matchCount to zero.
      var first = $(data.element).closest('select').find('option').first().val();
      if (first == data.id) matchCount = 0;
      
      // If there was a match against this option, record it
      if (match) {
        matchCount = matchCount + 1;
        matched = data.id;
      }
      
      // If this is the last option that we are testing against,
      // now is a good time to check how many matches we had.
      var last = $(data.element).closest('select').find('option').last().val();
      if (last == data.id && matchCount == 1) {
        
        // There was only one match, change the value to the
        // matched option and close the dropdown box.
        $(data.element).closest('select')
          .val(matched).trigger('change')
          .select2('close');
        return null;
      }
      
      // Return the default match as normal. Null if no match.
      return match;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select style="width: 20em">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="100">Product One</option>
  <option value="200">Product Two</option>
  <option value="300">Product Three</option>
  <option value="400">Product Four</option>
  <option value="500">Product Five</option>
</select>
```